# Android - How to know if my WiFi has blocked any services

Tags: android, wifi

Hello I'm wondering if exist some method or something to detect if my current `WiFi` has blocked some services like `WhatsApp`, `FaceBook`, `Instagram`, etc... You know that there are some `WiFi` that you can't send `WhatsApp` messages, but you can still using `Google Search`, so you have connection...

Answer (score 0):

Android tests a connection to Google servers. If individual services are blocked, you won't know.

Many services using Google Cloud Messaging, so some of those services will get through even if the service is block but Google & Google Cloud Messaging is allowed.

You could use individual services APIs to test connections.

Comment: So you are saying to me that I can't detect if any service is blocked from my WiFi? what do you mean a "individual services APIs"?